# iterate and extract individual item in a javascript object

Tags: javascript, object

I have an object and I want to loop through it to retrieve each element.

```
  result = {@danby:[{will:2, qwerty:5}]}

  for (i in result) {
          for (j in result[i]){

          console.log(result[i][j])
           }
       }
```

This gives me [object Object]. Any help please

Comment: `{@danby: value}` is an invalid object initializer.

Comment: `console.log(JSON.stringify(result[i][j]))` with this you can see wahts in the object

Answer (score 0):

You should **not** use `for..in` for iterating arrays.

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in)

> for...in should not be used to iterate over an Array where the index order is important.

Use plain for loop

```js
result = {
    '@danby': [{ //⬅️ use quotes here
        will: 2,
        qwerty: 5
    }]
}

for (i in result) {
    for (var j = 0; j < result[i].length; j++) {
        document.write(JSON.stringify(result[i][j]));//⬅️ use 'stringify' to output your object 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to log each element, assuming you fix your object by putting quotes around that illegal key name, you can just iterate over the array:

```
result['@danby'].forEach(function (el) {
  console.log(el); // { will: 2, qwerty: 5 }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an object within `result[i][j]`, So iterate this object another round . **[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nh6092d4/)**

```js
result = {
  '@danby': [{
    will: 2,
    qwerty: 5
  }]
}

for (i in result) {
 for (var j = 0; j < result[i].length; j++) {
    for (k in result[i][j]) {
      alert(result[i][j][k]);
    }
  }
}
```

Also make your object valid by adding `' '` around the property `@danby`

Comment: You shouldn't use `for..in` for arrays.

Comment: @Andy updated my answer, Thanks but what is the reason?

Comment: *for...in should not be used to iterate over an Array where the index order is important.*

Comment: Also, it will pick up any other enumerable properties you might have given the array. `var a = [1, 2]; a.foo = 'foo'` will log `1, 2, foo` if you use `for...in`.

Comment: @Andy Thanks for that info.

Comment: @isvforall Thank you too.